# Caching google maps in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-maps, caching

Can I caching google maps in Windows Phone? I use `GoogleTileSource`:

```
<my:MapTileLayer Name="street" Margin="0,0,0,32" Height="800" Width="433">
     <my:MapTileLayer.TileSources>
           <GoogleTileSource:GoogleTile TileTypes="Street"/>
     </my:MapTileLayer.TileSources>
</my:MapTileLayer>
```

It's possible?

Thank in advance.

**UPDATE**

`XAML` code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <my:Map Height="756" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="googlemap"
                   CredentialsProvider="AqayajnZU8FSfDGL8jpK5zMKAHmUL27Uqxv_OnpQzJQOI2PoQyxcG7dlR6_g4WWo" 
                   CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" 
                   ScaleVisibility="Visible"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" >
                <my:Map.Mode>
                    <MSPCMCore:MercatorMode/>
                </my:Map.Mode>
                <my:MapTileLayer Name="street" Margin="0,0,0,32" Height="800" Width="433">
                    <my:MapTileLayer.TileSources>
                        <GoogleTileSource:GoogleTile TileTypes="Street"/>
                    </my:MapTileLayer.TileSources>
                </my:MapTileLayer>
                <my:MapLayer x:Name="PopupLayer">
                    <Canvas x:Name="ContentPopup" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="ContentPopupRectangle" Fill="Black" 
                                   Opacity="0.6" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" 
                                   Height="100" Width="200"/>
                        <StackPanel Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="10">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ContentPopupNickname" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ContentPopupLocation" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ContentPopupAge" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200"/>                              
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Canvas>
                </my:MapLayer>
            </my:Map>
        </Grid>
```

So, `cs` code:

```
    public enum GoogleTileTypes
    {
        Hybrid,
        Physical,
        Street,
        Satellite,
        WaterOverlay
    }

    public class GoogleTile : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.TileSource
    {
        private int _server;
        private char _mapmode;
        private GoogleTileTypes _tiletypes;

        public GoogleTileTypes TileTypes
        {
            get { return _tiletypes; }
            set
            {
                _tiletypes = value;
                MapMode = MapModeConverter(value);
            }
        }

        public char MapMode
        {
            get { return _mapmode; }
            set { _mapmode = value; }
        }

        public int Server
        {
            get { return _server; }
            set { _server = value; }
        }

        public GoogleTile()
        {
            UriFormat = @"http://mt{0}.google.com/vt/lyrs={1}&z={2}&x={3}&y={4}";
            Server = 0;
        }

        public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel)
        {
            if (zoomLevel > 0)
            {
                var Url = string.Format(UriFormat, Server, MapMode, zoomLevel, x, y);
                return new Uri(Url);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private char MapModeConverter(GoogleTileTypes tiletype)
        {
            switch (tiletype)
            {
                case GoogleTileTypes.Hybrid:
                    {
                        return 'y';
                    }
                case GoogleTileTypes.Physical:
                    {
                        return 't';
                    }
                case GoogleTileTypes.Satellite:
                    {
                        return 's';
                    }
                case GoogleTileTypes.Street:
                    {
                        return 'm';
                    }
                case GoogleTileTypes.WaterOverlay:
                    {
                        return 'r';
                    }
            }
            return ' ';
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have not tried it, until I don't know how it is possible to cache maps, what technologies to use. You mean where I use `GoogleTileSource`? In update I show full code. By the way, if you know how to cache Bing maps, one can consider the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard TileSource doesn't allow you any control over the downloading of the tile images.

If you want to add your own caching you'll have to add another Layer to the map and then download the images and load them into the extra layer in the correct position yourself. It's not fun but it can be done.